# Iterating through a MySQL query back and foward [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql

I used to use VBA to loop throug a Microsoft Access table. I used a recordeset and then depending on the conditions I move previous or next or  to the first row.

Now I am using MySQL and PHP.

> $qry = $conn -> prepare("SELECT * FROM pes");
>
> $qry -> execute();
>
> while ($row = $qry -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
>
> ```
>      echo $row['Date'].' - ' .$row['Time']. ' - ' .$row['State']. '<br>';
> ```
>
> }

My problem is that I cannot go previous and next by this away. I need to to be able to move through the query depending on some conditions.

Thank you

Comment: you'd need a cursor for going backwards, and mysql's cursors are "non-scrollable".  You'd be better off caching the data client-side and going "backwards" in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add all of the results to an `array` and then do a `for` loop in which you could access any of the rows by numerical index:

```
while ($row = $qry -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $rows[] = $row;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++) {
   $row = $rows[$i];
   $previous = $rows[$i-1];
   $next = $rows[$i+1];
}
```

The only problem with that code is that there isn't always a previous/next (first/last iterations). For that we could use ternary operators and assign null in that case:

```
while ($row = $qry -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $rows[] = $row;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++) {
   $row = $rows[$i];
   $previous = $i > 0 ? $rows[$i-1] : null;
   $next = $i+1 < count($rows) ? $rows[$i+1] : null;
}
```

Comment: or use next(), prev(), reset() or other [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. But imagine that I am going through the for loop and due to a condition I need to check the previous $i, how can I do that? Then I need to go again to the current $i to keep on looping! Thank you, You were a great help!

Comment: Using this approach if you want to 'go again' on the current row, you can just decrement `$i` (decrease it's value by one to offset it increasing after that iteration has ran). Using `next`, `current` and `prev` array functions as mentioned by VMai is also an option after you've built up the array rather than a `for` loop. Use whichever you think is best suited.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this approch. But just a question. If I use the next(), prev() and reset() and do I iterate through the array?